# Ignore backslash in django url patterns

Tags: django, url

In my django project, I have a url pattern like

`(r'^survey/u2=([^/]+)/u3=([^/]+)/$',SurveyView.as_view())`.

When I try to open the below url

http://www.sample.com/survey/u2=rc57S4/jyTJBz+==/u3=/U5pKfrV8X1MjUU2tI0AhqTF5PGR8g=/

`[where u2 & u3 are encrypted value using internal keys. ]`

I'm getting `page not found` error. This is due to, the sample url is not matching with the original url pattern at server end, as it has '/' backslash character in the url parameter.

Right now,I'm not in a position to edit the sample url by adding encode to the parameters, since this url has been mailed to customer. However if the customer opens the link I should not through error message.

How can I handle this special characters at server end while pattern match for url?.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing as arguments in URL pass it as a GET request. seperated by ? and & characters.